# How to make vinyl flooring stable in bathroom?

Tags: vinyl-flooring

In my bathroom I've put vinyl flooring on top of some sort of underlay but the vinyl is moving and creasing a lot:

[image: Creasing]

Here's what is underneath, a blue underlay and then the wooden floor under that:

[image: Underlay]

What's the quickest way to make this vinyl stable? What about stapling it? In this case, how many millimeters extra (beyond thickness of the vinyl itself) are required?

Comment: Double stick carpet tape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Staple down the underlay, and then I'd go with @mike's suggestion of double-sided carpet tape.

Installing molding around the edges will also help to hold it down and prevent buckling, especially if it's relatively thick (eg, includes quarter-round) and tight to the floor.

[image: installing quarter-round]

Answer (score 3):

Normally vinyl is just glued down.  [Robert's](http://www.zorotools.com/g/00147826/k-G5123684?utm_source=google_shopping&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Google_Shopping_Feed&kw=%7Bkeyword%7D&gclid=CPfvk8nX-LgCFdKj4Aodm0IAHQ)  adhesive can be bought at the big box.  Loctite makes glue for vinyl that can be bought in a caulking tube.  You just need to lay some heavy things on the floor after you glue and let it sit for a half day or so.